# How can I find a duplicate copy of an image file?

Tags: grep

I have an image file, and I know there's another copy of it somewhere in a directory or one of its ancestors, but it has a different, unknown file name, and there are thousands of images in this directory.

How can I find the file name of the image that's the same as the one I do know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, find all files with the exact same file size, then do a binary compare.

```
s=$(stat -c "%s" $file)    #File size in bytes
for i in $(find $dir -size "${s}c"); do    #by default, find expects sizes in blocks
  if cmp "$i" "$file"; then
    echo "$file and $i identical"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [bgrep](https://github.com/tmbinc/bgrep). Open the known image in a hex editor and copy some arbitrary chunk in the middle. Suppose that chunk is "21310441125161320581C113F071B122". Then use bgrep to search the directory for that chunk:

`bgrep 21310441125161320581C113F071B122 images_directory`